# Creating labels for the entire organizations in GitHub

Tags: github

Labels are useful. But if I want to have custom labels, I'd have to manually create them per repo https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-label/.

I'd want to be able to create custom labels at the organization level, so that all repositories have the same labels.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is now supported directly in Github:
> https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-default-labels-for-repositories-in-your-organization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer (Sep. 2018)

Since there does not seem to be organisation-wide labels, you would need to script the creation process by using the GitHub API and:

- listing [all repositories in an orignation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)
- creating [the label in each repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#create-a-label)

---

Update [Oct. 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-17-create-default-labels-at-the-organization-level/)

### Create default labels at the organization level

> Organization administrators can visit the new Repository labels setting to standardize the default set of labels which will be added when new repositories are created.
>
> Adding or removing default organization labels in settings will not modify existing repositories

See more at "**[Managing default labels for repositories in your organization](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-default-labels-for-repositories-in-your-organization)**"

[image: repo labels]

Comment: Is there an API to get the Organization -> Repository Defaults -> Repository labels?

Comment: @JimBledsoe Looking at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos, I don't see one for default labels.

Comment: thanks for the sanity check.